# PHP 5.6 Flatten multidimensional array with multiple fields

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'a1' => boolean true
      'b1' => string 'abc' (length=6)
      'c1' => string 'def' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'a2' => boolean true
      'b2' => string 'fgh' (length=6)
      'c2' => string 'ijk' (length=8)
      'd2' => string 'lmn' (length=4)
      'e2' => string 'opq' (length=4)
```

And my goal is to get this:

```
array (size=8)
  'a1' => boolean true
  'b1' => string 'abc' (length=6)
  'c1' => string 'def' (length=8)
  'a2' => boolean true
  'b2' => string 'fgh' (length=6)
  'c2' => string 'ijk' (length=8)
  'd2' => string 'lmn' (length=4)
  'e2' => string 'opq' (length=4)
```

I've tried something with the array_map function but I don't know how to get all fields:

```
$params = array_map(function($element) {
    return $element['a1'];
}, $params);
```

Comment: I really don’t know why people always insist on failing stuff like this by looking for complex array functions - for basic stuff that could be done using simple loops …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this :

```
function array_flatten($array) {
    if (!is_array($array)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value));
        }
        else {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I test it with :

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'a1' => true,
        'b1' => 'abc',
        'c1' => 'def',
    ),
    1 => array(
        'a2' => true,
        'b2' => 'fgh',
        'c2' => 'ijk',
        'd2' => 'lmn',
        'e2' => 'opq'
    )
);

$result = array_flatten($array);

var_dump($result);
```

The output is :

```
array (size=8)
    'a1' => boolean true
    'b1' => string 'abc' (length=3)
    'c1' => string 'def' (length=3)
    'a2' => boolean true
    'b2' => string 'fgh' (length=3)
    'c2' => string 'ijk' (length=3)
    'd2' => string 'lmn' (length=3)
    'e2' => string 'opq' (length=3)
```

But I prefer to be honnest, I think it's a function I got from a duplicate question, can't find it again ! But I used it to "flatten" some array and it works well :)

Comment: I get this error in my IDE `undefined function array_flatten()`

Comment: Well, my function is called `array_flatten()` :) And you need to add it before executing it !

Comment: oh okay I see you use the same function I thought it might be a built-in function from PHP

Comment: @MikloV : If you are using class use `$this->array_flatten()`

Answer (score 4):

Use `call_user_func_array()` like:

```
  $arr1=array ( 
        array (
          'a1' => true,
          'b1' => 'abc',
          'c1' => 'def'), 
        array (
          'a2' => true,
          'b2' => 'fgh',
          'c2' => 'ijk',
          'd2' => 'lmn',
          'e2' => 'opq'));
        $res=call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr1);
    print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [a1] => 1 [b1] => abc [c1] => def [a2] => 1 [b2] => fgh [c2] => ijk 
[d2] => lmn [e2] => opq )
```

Read about [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use loop to merge array

```
<?php
$arr = [
  ["a1"=>true,"b1"=>"abc"],
  ["a2"=>true,"b2"=>"fgh"]
];
$new = [];
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
  $new = array_merge($new,$val);
}
print_r($new);
?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1013617)

Or by `...array_values`, About [...](https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/php-5-6-and-the-splat-operator)

```
<?php
$arr = [
  ["a1"=>true,"b1"=>"abc"],
  ["a2"=>true,"b2"=>"fgh"]
];
$arr = array_merge(...array_values($arr));
print_r($arr);
?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1013614)

Comment: `array_merge(...$array);` will do here.

Answer (score 0):

For the data in your example, you might use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php), pass and empty array as the initial value and add the arrays:

```
$arrays = [
    [
        "a1" => true,
        "b1" => "abc",
        "c1" => "def"
    ],
    [
        "a2" => true,
        "b2" => "fgh",
        "c2" => "ijk",
        "d2" => "lmn",
        "e2" => "opq"
    ]
];

$result = array_reduce($arrays, function ($carry, $item) {
        $carry += $item;
        return $carry;
}, []);

var_dump($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/2jatR)

That will result in:

```
array(8) {
  ["a1"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["b1"]=>
  string(3) "abc"
  ["c1"]=>
  string(3) "def"
  ["a2"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["b2"]=>
  string(3) "fgh"
  ["c2"]=>
  string(3) "ijk"
  ["d2"]=>
  string(3) "lmn"
  ["e2"]=>
  string(3) "opq"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
$d = array (
array (
'a1' => true,
'b1' => 'abc' ,
'c1' => 'def' ),
array (
'a2' => true,
'b2' => 'fgh',
'c2' => 'ijk' ,
'd2' => 'lmn' ,
'e2' => 'opq' ));

function flatten(array $array)
{
    $result = array();
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $result = array_merge($result, flatten($v));
            } else {
                $result[$k] = $v;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$dd = flatten($d);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($dd);
echo "</pre>";
```

DEMO: https://3v4l.org/jtUoq

Comment: I get the following error in my IDE `undefined function flatten()`

Comment: have you added function?

Comment: I think he is using class, so try `$this->flatten()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `RecursiveIteratorIterator`. From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php).

> Can be used to iterate through recursive iterators.

Example:

```
<?php

$arr = [
    [
      'a1' => true,
      'b1' => 'abc',
      'c1' => 'def'
    ],
    [
      'a2' => true,
      'b2' => 'fgh',
      'c2' => 'ijk',
      'd2' => 'lmn',
      'e2' => 'opq',
    ]
];

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));

foreach($iterator as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($key . ': ' . $value);
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/QX9iQ

Answer (score 0):

```
$flatArray = array(); // an empty array where we will store rest of arrays

foreach($multiArray as $item){
$flatArray = array_merge($flatArray,$item); //get arrays and merge into main array
}
```

Comment: This code has syntax errors.  And even if corrected `$flatArray` would be empty.  Correct and run your code and inspect then resulting arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Reach for foreach:

```
<?php

$data =
[
    [
        'foo' => true,
        'bar' => false
    ],
    [
        'baz' => true,
        'bat' => true
    ]
];

$out = [];
foreach($data as $item)
    foreach($item as $k => $v)
        $out[$k] = $v;

var_export($out);
```

Output:

```
array (
'foo' => true,
'bar' => false,
'baz' => true,
'bat' => true,
)
```